# Gibt es Verben mit drei oder mehr Präfixen?

Tags: verb, prefix, curiosity

**Existieren im Deutschen Verben mit drei oder mehr Präfixen?**

Es spielt keine Rolle, ob diese trennbar sind oder nicht. Ich habe mich schon an einigen Wortungetümen, etwa *zwangsverabreichen*, versucht, bin mir allerdings nicht sicher, ob es als vollwertiges Wort angesehen werden kann. Auf mehr als drei Präfixe kann ich leider beim besten Willen nicht kommen. Könnte mir jemand dabei auf die Sprünge helfen?

Comment: Ein vollwertiges Wort ist *zwangsverabreichen* sicherlich. Die Frage wäre eher, ob man *zwangs* als Präfix ansehen will. Dann wäre ja auch *heimat* ein Präfix (*heimatbeurlaubt*) und *pflicht* (*pflichtvergessen*).

Comment: Kennst du https://www.verblisten.de/? Dort kannst du auch nach Vorsilben suchen.

Comment: "Hilft mir jemand, das Abo abzubestellen?" - Das Zu darin ist aber wohl vom Infinitiv, kein Präfix.

Comment: *Ich rate Ihnen, im Haushalt für 2019 keine höheren Summen zu verbeanschlagen*. Nicht dass es gutes Deutsch wäre... aber vorkommendes Deutsch ist es wohl.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann In dieser Richtung gibt's noch mehr Beispiele, z.B. "vorveranschlagen".

Comment: "nebenverabreden" ist auch nett

Answer (score 4):

Solche Fragen versuche ich gerne mit Hilfe von Skripten, die ich auf mein Wörterbuch loslasse, zu beantworten, und eine Suche nach 4 Präfixen liefert zunächst:

```
pfix="(ab|an|auf|aus|be|bei|dar|ein|er|ge|hin|hinter|nach|nieder|über|un|unter|ver|vor|weg|wider|zer|zu|zusammen)"; egrep "^$pfix$pfix$pfix$pfix" utf-german
```

152 Treffer, davon aber fast immer 6-8 Varianten wie

```
abgegeben
abgegebene
abgegebenem
abgegebenen
abgegebener
abgegebenes
```

so dass wohl 20-30 Grundformen übrig blieben. Allerdings ist das eine plumpe Zeichenkettensuche, die hier das *Ge* in *geben* fälschlich vereinnahmt hat.

Außerdem habe ich die Präfixe von der Wikipediaseite [Präfixe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4fix) gesammelt, auf der aber zwischen Präfixen und Partikeln unterschieden wird. Verengt auf im engeren Sinne Präfixe kommt keine Konstruktion mit vieren durch, und auch die mit dreien scheinen mir alle falsche Treffer zu sein - die 3 sind rasch genannt:

```
pfix="(be|er|hinter|über|unter|ver|wider|zer)"; egrep "^$pfix$pfix$pfix" utf-german
erbebendes
untererer
vererben
```

Be in *Beben* ist kein Präfix, weder *Er*, noch *Be* in *erben*. *Untererer* wäre überhaupt nur eine Präfixkette.

Allerdings will Wikipedia nicht vollständig sein, sondern nur die wichtigsten Präfixe genannt habe, und ob mein Wörterbuch vollständig ist, ist auch nicht entschieden. Da Präfixe nicht vom Verb trennbar sind, wäre das ein wichtiges Kriterium, diese Wörter alle aufzunehmen, im Ggs. zur Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschafterversammlungsrundfahrtsetappe, aber eine Garantie ist es natürlich nicht.

Mit mehr Präfixen wiederhole ich die Suche gerne, aber es ist natürlich jeder frei sich *grep* auch selbst zu installieren, so es noch fehlt, und eigene Wörterbücher zu durchforsten.

Answer (score 3):

Sofern man »vorbei« aufteilt in »vor« + »bei«:

> vorbeibenehmen

Answer (score 3):

Weitere Multipräfixverben des Deutschen bzw. der deutschsprachigen Amtsstube:

> rückbeantragen
>
> vorveranschlagen
>
> nachbegutachten

Ja, ja... einen Schönheitswettbewerb gewinnen solche Wörter selten.

---

**Am Rande vielleicht interessant**

Vorsilbenschlangen sind keine Spezialität nur des Deutschen. Die slavischen Sprachen sind allgemein sehr vorsilbenfreudig.

Bulgarisches Beispiel:

> обезвъздушавам - o-bez-vyz-dushavam - entlüften (z.B. eine Heizung)

Hier sind die Präfixe *o-*, *bez-*, und *vyz-*. Wobei man bei *vyz-* noch streiten kann, denn *vyzduch* (въздух) ist die Luft; aber der bulgarische *vyzduch* besteht eben wieder aus Vorsilbe *vyz-* und Kernwort *duch* (дух) - Geist, also etwa "Aufgeist". Silbe für Silbe übersetzt also etwa: ver-ent-auf-geisten.

Comment: "изпонаприказвам" ist auch ein schönes Beispiel dafür, auch wenn das Wort nur in der Umgangssprache Verwendung findet,

Comment: @Dreikäsehoch  Я виж ти!